# How to calculate that sum

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{n=0}^{2023}\frac{1}{2022^n + \sqrt{2022^{2023}}}$$

I found this example in math book, but without solution. So I decided to try to solve it. In my opinion, I can transform this in sequence like that:
$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2022a_n+\sqrt{2022^{2023}}}$, but I'm not sure in what I'm doing.

Can you explain how to calculate that. What method should I use?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: My first thought would be something to do with rationalising denominators, although I don't know if this will work.

Comment: I try to do something with them, but I'm not sure if it helps, because it still a very big number in denominator. I think I should transform it somehow.

Comment: Which math book has this problem? Considering the number $2023$ and the fact that it is still January of that year I would have thought this was a contest problem. Anyway, look at the techniques in that chapter of the book. That should give you a hint.

Comment: This book is just stapled sheets (25 pages) with different math problems. My university teacher gave it to me. It doesn't have chapters. I decided that this problem is very hard for me, so I gave up and moved to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the general form of this summation is:
$$
S = \sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{a^n+b}
$$
$b$ here is $a^{N/2}$.
first you can simplify the sum with factoring $b$ :
$$
S = \frac{1}{2022^{\frac{2023}{2}}} \sum_{n=0}^{2023} \frac{1}{2022^{(n-2023/2)}+1}
$$
then you can observe that for summing only $n$ and $(2023-n)$ we get :
$$
\frac{1}{2022^{n-2023/2}+1} + \frac{1}{2022^{2023-n-2023/2}+1} = \frac{1}{2022^{n-2023/2}+1} + \frac{1}{2022^{2023/2-n}+1}  = 1
$$
because
$$
\frac{1}{a^{x}+1} + \frac{1}{a^{-x}+1} = \frac{1}{a^{x}+1} + \frac{a^{x}}{a^{x}+1} = \frac{a^{x}+1}{a^{x}+1} = 1 
$$
so we just need to write summation in 2 part :
$$
S = \frac{1}{2022^{\frac{2023}{2}}} \big(\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor \frac{2023}{2} \rfloor} \frac{1}{2022^{(n-2023/2)}+1} +  \sum_{\lfloor \frac{2023}{2} \rfloor + 1}^{2023} \frac{1}{2022^{(n-2023/2)}+1} \big)
$$
for every index in the first sum there's an index ($2023-n$) in the second sum that adding these two sentences together gives 1. so :
$$
S = \frac{1}{2022^{\frac{2023}{2}}} ( \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor \frac{2023}{2} \rfloor} 1) = \frac{\lfloor \frac{2023}{2} \rfloor + 1}{\sqrt{2022^{2023}}} = \frac{1012}{\sqrt{2022^{2023}}}
$$